# How does Google hide the DOM of sheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-sheets, web-inspector

When I open a Google spreadsheet and look in the Elements tab of the Chrom developer tools, this is all I see for the spreadsheet's cells:

```
<div class="goog-inline-block grid4-inner-container" style="width: 1580px; height: 646px;">
    <div class="waffle-background-container">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="scrollable_right_1" class="uberlay" style="display: none;">
        <div class="overlay-container-ltr" style="z-index: 8;"></div>
        <div class="overlay-container-ltr" style="z-index: 5;"></div>
        <div class="overlay-container-ltr" style="z-index: 7;"></div>
        <div class="overlay-container-ltr" style="z-index: 6;"></div>
        <div class="overlay-container-ltr" style="z-index: 8;"></div>
        <div class="overlay-container-ltr" style="z-index: 6;"></div>
        <div class="overlay-container-ltr" style="z-index: 7;"></div>
        <div class="overlay-container-ltr" style="z-index: 7;"></div>
        <div class="overlay-container-ltr" style="z-index: 7;"></div>
    </div>
    ..etc... repeated 20 times
</div>
```

Most of this DOM is display:none, and none of the data in the spreadsheet is represented in this DOM. This is not the case in a normal HTML table, nor any of the grid components I have used, in which every cell I see on the screen is represented by at least one node in the DOM. How does Google do this?

Comment: You'll see it if you open the raw HTML source (typically Ctrl+U) of an existing document. It's just a terribly convoluted HTML and CSS combination due to stuff being generated programmatically.

Comment: The "raw HTML" is what I showed in the question. There is no representation in the DOM of the cells. My guess is they are painting the whole sheet in the canvas, but I wasn't sure. Or can you show me some of the HTML you mean?

Comment: You said Elements tab... It isn't the same.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I've grown so complacent with browser dev tools that I've left the source. I would guess that's a good lesson for others too. Make that an answer please.

Comment: Odd. With a small sheet I indeed see the td's with the data when I view source. But take a larger sheet, say some thousand rows and hundreds of columns. When I edit a cell far from the origin and then view source there are no relevant nodes with that content. Instead in the head there's a <meta property="og:description" content="Sheet1   Hello SO"> - how does that get translated on the screen as a cell without leaving a td?


 fish
 Hello SO
 dog">

Comment: I don't know enough about the system as to compose a decent answer. It's a heavy JavaScript app so I presume most information is dynamically generated in the browser. I just wanted to highlight that a really convoluted CSS mayhem (as it seems to be the case) can be hard to debug with browser tools but it isn't really an advanced technique to hide anything.

Answer (score 2):

I believe everything is rendered in a Canvas element, and the `<div class="goog-inline-block grid4-inner-container" ....>` that you found above is probably meant for something else.

In the dev console, try `$$("canvas")`, and it should return one canvas object for that entire document/window. Click on that to see its properties. If you change the "top" or "left" properties, you'll see the whole spreadsheet shifting up or down, or left or right.

That should answer your question, but beyond that, I have no idea how to inspect or modify inside Canvas elements.